# I have deleted my path variable in Environment variable how can I now add MinGw compiler

Tags: environment-variables, mingw, path-variables

I have deleted my path variable in Environment variable how can I now add MinGw compiler.How can I now add path for MinGw compiler in my device .Pls Help....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never add the location of the MinGW compiler to my PATH. The main reason is that I sometimes use different MinGW/MinGW-w64 toolchains on the same system.

You can open a Command Prompt or MSYS2 shell and add the MinGW's bin location to the PATH for just that session.

In Command Prompt that would look like:

```
SET PATH=C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin
```

or in MSYS2 shell:

```
export PATH=/C/MinGW/mingw32/bin:$PATH
```

Or if you use an IDE you can specify the path there, so that also doesn't require a global PATH environment variable setting. See https://winlibs.com/#usage-codeblocks for an example on how to do this with MinGW-w64 and Code::Blocks.

Comment: Can you pls tell me how can I do this on visual studio code.

Comment: See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw